# Cleanest way to set multiple object keys

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Hi I was working on a text parser and I was wondering if there was a clean to rewrite the following code. Concerning the way that an object's properties are set.

```js
         //In the real case the parser returns varying result based on the param
         const parserResult = {'value':2,'syntaxError':false,'NaNError':false}     
         const {value,syntaxError,NaNError} = parserResult
         const param = {someProperty:'any value'} //can have any properties
         //the problem under here
         param['value'] = value
         param['syntaxError'] = syntaxError
         param['NaNError'] = NaNError
         console.log(param)
```

Setting three properties like that one after an other is not all that eloquent does anyone now a cleaner solution? Thanks in advance.
(complete code to test under here)

```js
  const parseParam = param => {
         //In the real case the parser returns varying result based on the param

     const parserResult = {'value':2,'syntaxError':false,'NaNError':false}     
     const {value,syntaxError,NaNError} = parserResult
     param['value'] = value
     param['syntaxError'] = syntaxError
     param['NaNError'] = NaNError
     return param
    }
    
 const parameters = [{someProperty:'test'},{someProperty:'someValue'}]
 const parsedParameters = parameters.map(parseParam)
 console.log(parsedParameters)
```

Comment: Is there any reason for not using the spread operator? Something like `param = { ...parserResult, additionalParam1: 'a', additionalParam2: 'b' }`

Comment: @secan Yes. I forgot to mention that the param could have the same value as the parser object. Though I will just approve Ekaterina 's answer using the spread operator as it will be more usefull in most cases and I have found a different approach avoiding this problem.

Comment: @JipHelsen Do you mind sharing that approach, so it helps more people? You can edit your question

Comment: @JipHelsen It's ok that there will be the same value as a field in the parser object. It'll be just rewritten with the new value

Comment: @yuriy636 it involves not putting the parser object into the parameter :) so this piece of code became unfortunately  completely redundant and the solution is very specific to my particular case. Therefor I think it is not all that interesting to share.

Comment: @Ekaterina I was unaware of that your  solution sure is usefull if I hadn't removed the code entierly. But I will remember it in the future : ) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this kind of stuff.

It will look like this:

```
const param = {...parserResult, someProperty:'any value'}
```

Comment: Thx! I'll approve asap.